# PDOException: could not find driver Line: 25

Tags: php, postgresql, ubuntu

Details

> Type: PDOException
>   Message: could not find driver
>   File: /home/conslet/project/webservice/src/dependencies.php
>   Line: 25

Trace

> 0 /home/conslet/project/webservice/src/dependencies.php(25): PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=128....', 'postgres', '1234')
>    1 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php(113): {closure}(Object(Slim\Container))
>    2 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Container.php(123): Pimple\Container->offsetGet('db')
>    3 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Container.php(172): Slim\Container->get('db')
>    4 /home/conslet/project/webservice/src/routes.php(5): Slim\Container->__get('db')
>    5 [internal function]: Closure->{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
>    6 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
>    7 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(344): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
>    8 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>    9 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(316): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>    10 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(476): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>    11 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>    12 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(370): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>    13 /home/conslet/project/webservice/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(295): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>    14 /home/conslet/project/webservice/public/index.php(30): Slim\App->run()
>    15 {main}

```
$container['db'] = function ($c) {

   $db = $c['settings']['db'];
   $pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=" . $db['host'] . ";dbname=" . $db['name'], $db['user'], $db['password']);
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $pdo;

};
```

Comment: Do you have `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` installed and enabled?

Comment: Do you get anything back if you run `php -m | grep pdo_pgsql` or `php -i | grep pgsql`?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you do not have the [php_pdo_pgsql](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_PGSQL/download/) extension installed/loaded.

You need to install it and enable it in `php.ini`. The configuration line should be `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.so` on UNIX/Linux systems, or `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` on Windows)